# Getting Insufficient Privilege error in Jmeter for Salesforce Application

Tags: performance, jmeter, salesforce, performance-testing

While doing performance testing for SFDC facing the Insufficient Privilege error on saving one of the object from Jmeter. There is no issue manually in application not any error in debug logs. This is happening only from jmeter. Have checked with Fiddler no requests are getting missed and also all the correlations are in place.

Jmeter Text Logs :

Insufficient Privileges

You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Comment: You seem to be missing out some id that authorizes you to complete that action. Check request and find all the parameters that are being sent.

Comment: @rachnabafna .I have verified with recorded request. Have checked by using fiddler if some requests are getting missed in jmeter. Have re verified all the corelations but still no luck.  What more can be done?

Comment: Did you check the headers? Compare the actual headers and ones that you are sending as part of your JMeter request.

Comment: @rachnabafna. I have checked them. Except the cookie everything is similar that of recorded one. I am using the Cookie manager which should handle the cookie. But the sids and some others info which are getting passed in header cookie are different at different place. if it is impacting the flow then how it can be mitigate?

Comment: Can you check for the cookies that are being sent in your JMeter requests. At times the cookies are not properly managed by cookie manager

Comment: @rachnabafna. Was trying to manipulate the cookies. But there are several cookies which being sent. Not sure which one to check. Not sure if it is the root cause of the problem. Any correct procedure to change the cookies! Please provide some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related tokens encoding. Hence while sending the some of the tokens to servers Jmeter is not encoding some of them and sending with extra spaces and characters. Therefore server is sending this insufficient privilege error and not saving the objects. Checked the encode parameters check boxes and Jmeter started sending as server expected.